# PDO не видит объект query()

Tags: php_pdo, php

PDO объект создается, но метод query() не видит. В чем ошибка?

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method DbConn::query()

В строке: `$query = self::getInstance()->query($sql)->fetch();`

```
class DbConn{
    const DB_NAME = 'test';
    const DB_LOGIN = 'root';
    const DB_PASS = '';

    private $_db;
    static private $_instance = null;

    private function __construct(){
        $this->_db = new PDO("mysql:host=openserver; dbname=".self::DB_NAME,self::DB_LOGIN,self::DB_PASS);
    }
    private function __clone(){}

    static function getInstance(){
        if(self::$_instance == null){
            self::$_instance = new DbConn();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }
    public function jl_query($sql){
        $query = self::getInstance()->query($sql)->fetch();
        return $query;

    }

}

$sql = "SELECT name FROM client WHERE id=1";
$db = DbConn::getInstance();
$db->jl_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну так-то метод `getInstance()` возвращает объект класса DbConn а не класса PDO. А вот приватная `$_db` переменная класса DbConn как раз таки и является экземпляром класса PDO.

Чтоб ваш код был рабочим, я сделал бы метод класса вот так:

```
public function jl_query($sql){
    $query = $this->_db->query($sql)->fetch();
    return $query;
}
```

Comment: при много благодарен, недоглядел)